# Determinant with tangent functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant

> Proof:\begin{equation}
>    \text{det}  \begin{pmatrix}
>      1 & 1 & 1 \\
>      \tan A & \tan B & \tan C \\
>      \tan 2A & \tan 2B & \tan 2C
>    \end{pmatrix}=0
>    \end{equation} where A+B+C=$2\pi$.

This problem of course can be prove by expand this determinant explicitly and calculate it.I wonder if there exists a more convenient way.

This determinant has a representation as 
$
\sum_{cyc}\{\tan B\tan 2C-\tan C\tan 2B\}
$

Comment: Probably the vandermonde matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's true?

Take $A=100^{\circ},$ $B=120^{\circ}$ and $C=140^{\circ}.$

By the way, the following reasoning can be interesting.

Let $\tan A=a$, $\tan B=b$ and $\tan C=c$.

Thus, $a+b+c=abc$ and
$$\Delta=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2bc}{1-c^2}-\frac{2bc}{1-b^2}\right)=\frac{2}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1-a^2)}\sum_{cyc}bc(c^2-b^2)(1-a^2)=$$
$$=\frac{2}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1-a^2)}\sum_{cyc}(a^3c-a^3b+a^3c^2b-a^3b^2c)=$$
$$=
\frac{2(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c+abc)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1-a^2)}.$$